# How many one-to-one functions there $\phi$ from $\{1,2,3,4,5,\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $\phi(i)\neq i$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$

Tags: functions

How many functions one-to-one  $\phi$  from $\{1,2,3,4,5,\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $\phi(i)\neq i$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$

**my attempt:**

the number of one-to-one functions  $\phi$  from $\{1,2,3,4,5,\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is 5!=120

and given condition is  $\phi(i)\neq i$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$ so these are 5

so number of one-to-one functions are   $\phi$  from $\{1,2,3,4,5,\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $\phi(i)\neq i$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$

=120-5=55  is i am right

Comment: You have $5!$ injective functions, which is $120$. Now count how many injections you get when you allow one fixed point, two fixed points etc and subtract from $120$. Inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Have a look at [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could interpret your functions as the result of shuffling a 5-card deck.
The number of outcomes where one card only is in the original position is given by (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle, “Counting Derangements” section) $$ W(n) = \sum_{p=1}^{n}  \frac{n!}{p!}$$
So, $W(5) = 76$, and the number you look for is given by $120 – 76 = 44$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are asking for the number of derangements of 5 intergers.i.e., $D_5$.
The general formula for derangements of n intergers is 
$$D_n=n!\left(1-1/1!+1/2!-1/3!+\cdots+ (-1)^n/n!\right) $$.
Substitute the value for n as 5 you will get the answer.

Comment: Fun fact! $D_n$ can be computed by finding $n! / e$, and rounding to the nearest integer.